# Updating outside React component

Tags: reactjs

I have a component for displaying news somewhere in the page. You can rate news (give stars to it).

I have another component in another place where some news are displayed. In that component you can rate the news as well. I want to update `News` component (rerender it) after a vote was given in `<SomeComponentWhereNewsAreDisplayed />`. Is there a way to do it?

Some pseudocode:

```
class SomeComponentWhereNewsAreDisplayed extends React.Component
{
    voteAndUpdateNewsComponent() {
         updateNewsComponent()
    }
    render() {
        return <div>
            ...
            <some functionality that allows to give a star to news onClick={this.voteAndUpdateNewsComponent}>
            ...
        </div>
    }
}

class News extends React.Component
{
    componentDidMount() {
        //..ajax request to get ratings, or taking it from localStorage, etc..
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            {this.state.ratings.map(rating => { return <span>{rating.stars}</span>})
        </div>
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can use state management like Redux or Context for solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, if two React components don't belong in the same component hierarchy, they cannot exchange data. There are a number of hacks to go around these, but ideally you want to put them in the same hierarchy and exchange props and callbacks.

If you don't want to do that, you still have Redux at your disposal to pull the state management out of the hierarchy: https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use a state container for this. Pass down a function from SomeComponentWhereNewsAreDisplayed to News that updates the state of SomeComponentWhereNewsAreDisplayed and is attached to the click handler of the star rating in News. This causes your parent (SomeComponentWhereNewsAreDisplayed) and its children to rerender.